# issue - browser adds a dotted border on active links

Tags: html, css, browser

I always wondered how to get rid of the dotted border that covers active links right afer clicked.
I tried `a:active { border:0;outline: none; }` and it didn't work. I don't think that is a border, that's something chrome adds, also firefox and ie add it their own shape.

Any help would be truly appreciated.
my code :

```
<ul class="footer-links">
<li id="main" class="icon-bookmark">help</li>
<a href="/forums/forum/discussions/#new-post"><li class="icon-pencil">new topic</li></a>
<a href="/contact"><li class="icon-chat">contact</li></a>
<a href="/forums/search/"><li class="icon-search">search</li></a>
<a href="/report"><li class="icon-flag">report</li></a>
</ul>
```

My link if needed : http://dvforum.elegance-style.com

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Those `<a>`s should be *inside* the `<li>`s, not the other way around. As it stands your markup is invalid.

Comment: thank you sir. I understood that but just wanted the links to be active on the entire line not on hovering linked text only. but later I added `display: block` and it worked on doing that, so working on your advise, `li` first, then `a`.
thanks man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the :focus class.

```
a:focus{ outline:none; }
```

You should however, consider adding alternative styles to this class, as purely disabling it will hinder usability.

Comment: thanks a lot. it worked. I am kind of stupid that I didn't figure that out already. accepting your answer when allowed.

Comment: This is terrible advice. Don't do it. http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20140916/F78

Comment: @danielnixon why the -1? The question was how to do it, not if you should do it, nor is it my advice. Furthermore, it is perfectly fine to apply this code, but you should naturally add some other visual styles to indicate the :focus state.